# Reasons for Python's isalpha/isnumeric/... vs. isascii inconsistency

Tags: python, string, built-in

[Python docs say](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html):

- str.isnumeric(): return True if /.../, and there is at least one character /.../
- str.isalpha(): return True if /.../ and there is at least one character /.../
- str.isdigit(): return True if /.../ and there is at least one character /.../

Similarly for many other functions.

However, the docs also specify

str.isascii(): Return True if the string is empty or /.../

**What is the reason for this inconsistency?**

Even though every character of the empty string is numeric and is alphabetic etc., I assume that the expected use cases of these functions silently assume that the strings are also non-empty (e.g., enter your phone number etc.). However, I would then assume that `str.isascii` would be treated the same way.

Comment: There is nothing in the docs that would indicate a clear reason for this. It might be worthwhile to make a github issue to ask this question: https://github.com/python/cpython

Comment: @joshmeranda Ok, will do that if there will be no answer explaining this.

Comment: The doc says it was introduced in 3.7, the "what's new in 3.7" links to its issue, and that links to a lengthy mailing list discussion about it. Have you read that? (Btw really irks me that it says "if the string is empty or all characters in the string are ASCII" instead of just the equivalent "if all characters in the string are ASCII"... what a pity for a generally pretty "mathy" language)

Comment: @KellyBundy Now, I have read it (kind of: read some of the emails, then go through the others in the search of the "empt", did not find anything).